# Keep Listbox at top of Scrolling Worksheet

Tags: excel, listbox, vba

I have a worksheet with about 2500 rows x 2 columns, A and B. I also have a listbox with information in Column C

How can I keep the listbox visible while I am scrolling the worksheet? Right now it scrolls with the worksheet and quickly it cannot be seen. I want it to stay in the viewing area of the scrolling worksheet.

I do not want to use a userform

The Listbox is large so I do not want to add it to row1 and freeze the row

I found this but from 2002 post and does not work for excel 2013

Thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myShape As Shape

Set myShape = Me.Shapes("Listbox1")

With Me.Cells(ActiveWindow.ScrollRow, ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn)
myShape.Top = .Top
myShape.Left = .Left
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for

Comment: No problem. Cheers~